# Not sure why buttons are not working on mobile

Tags: javascript

The touch buttons in mobile dev tools from chrome work just fine so I'm not sure why it's not working when I upload the site to GitHub. I added 'touchstart' to the each of the e listeners, but the buttons are not working on mobile. Maybe something to do with the functions inside the for loop with the Event Listeners...It must have something to do the Listeners being called in the loop, right? Theres no way for me to really test this because mobile chrome dev tools are wrong apparently. Just curious to know if anyone can spot the mistake/s
Code below:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');

for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  const y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  const x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  const colors = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  const speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 8) + 's';
  const balloon_el = document.createElement('div');
  balloon_el.classList.add('balloon');
  const triangle_el = document.createElement('div');
  triangle_el.classList.add('triangle');
  balloon_el.appendChild(triangle_el);
  const string_el = document.createElement('div');
  string_el.classList.add('string');
  balloon_el.appendChild(string_el);
  balloon_el.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px, 0)';
  balloon_el.style.animationDuration = speed;
  balloon_el.style.background = randomColor();
  triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
  body.appendChild(balloon_el);

  function purpleHurp() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'purple'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function orangeSpor() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'orange'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function blueFlu() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'blue'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function greenMean() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'green'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function yellowFellow() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'yellow'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function redFred() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'red'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function randomFandom() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      luminosity: 'light'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function cyanBuyin() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: '#00FFFF'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function pinky() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'pink'
    });
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'ghostwhite';
  }

  function dark() {
    balloon_el.style.background = randomColor({
      hue: 'monochrome'
    });
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.616)';
    triangle_el.style.borderBottom = balloon_el.style.background + '7px solid';
  }

  const dark_btn = document.getElementById('dark');
  dark_btn.addEventListener('click', dark);
  dark_btn.addEventListener('touchstart', dark)

  const pink = document.getElementById('pink');
  pink.addEventListener('click', pinky);
  pink.addEventListener('touchstart', pinky)

  const cyan = document.getElementById('cyan');
  cyan.addEventListener('click', cyanBuyin);
  cyan.addEventListener('touchstart', cyanBuyin)

  const random = document.getElementById('random');
  random.addEventListener('click', randomFandom);
  random.addEventListener('touchstart', randomFandom)

  const red = document.getElementById('red');
  red.addEventListener('click', redFred);
  red.addEventListener('touchstart', redFred)

  const yellow = document.getElementById('yellow');
  yellow.addEventListener('click', yellowFellow);
  yellow.addEventListener('touchstart', yellowFellow)

  const green = document.getElementById('green');
  green.addEventListener('click', greenMean);
  green.addEventListener('touchstart', greenMean)

  const blue = document.getElementById('blue');
  blue.addEventListener('click', blueFlu);
  blue.addEventListener('touchstart', blueFlu)

  const orange = document.getElementById('orange');
  orange.addEventListener('click', orangeSpor);
  orange.addEventListener('touchstart', orangeSpor)

  const purple = document.getElementById('purple');
  purple.addEventListener('click', purpleHurp);
  purple.addEventListener('touchstart', purpleHurp)
}
```

I tried setting e.preventDefault() in the functions, but that didn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't need to define touchstart listeners. touches are automatically converted to clicks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site where it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Here is the live link from github: https://wesclaw.github.io/50-balloons-with-colored-themes/